# Python - Checking for an empty input + script troubles

Tags: python, integer, try-catch, except

I am very knew to Python, so as expected, I'm encountering problems often when scripting and am usually not sure how to fix them.

I'm making a small game where you try and guess a number which the program has randomly chosen. I've gotten pretty far, but I noticed the program simply displayed an error message when I input nothing. I would like the program to display the text "Enter a number." in this situation, and then prompt the "Your guess: " input again, but after a lot of research, I'm really not sure how to successfully implement that feature into my code. My issue, specifically, is the "try and except" section - I don't really know how to write them properly, but I saw another post on here suggesting to use them.

```
import random

def question():
    print("Guess a number between 1 and 100.")
    randomNumber = random.randint(1, 100)
    found = False

    while not found:
        myNumber = int(input("Your guess: "), 10)
        try:
            myNumber = int(input("Your guess: "), 10)
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter a number.")

        if myNumber == randomNumber:
            print("Correct!")
            found = True
        elif myNumber > randomNumber:
            print("Wrong, guess lower!")
        else:
            print("Wrong, guess higher!")

question()
```

You should be able to see my intentions in the code I've written, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost right. Just continue to the next iteration after handling exception.

```
import random

def question():
    print("Guess a number between 1 and 100.")
    randomNumber = random.randint(1, 100)
    found = False

    while not found:
        try: 
            myNumber = int(input("Your guess: "), 10)
        except Exception:
            print('Enter a number.')
            continue

        if myNumber == randomNumber:
            print("Correct!")
            found = True
        elif myNumber > randomNumber:
            print("Wrong, guess lower!")
        else:
            print("Wrong, guess higher!")

question()
```

Comment: Olexander beat me to it. I would add that you probably need to catch other exceptions (e.g. `SyntaxError`) to handle the case when an empty line is entered. You could do something like `except (ValueError, SyntaxError):`. Or to be safe, you can catch any exception by using `except Exception:`.

Comment: I agree here. Catching all exceptions with `except Exception` might be better in this case. Edited answer.

Comment: you know, the questioner is on python 3. So use `input()` instead `raw_input()` :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It was really frustrating, can't believe the fix was so simple. Also, you mention about using `SyntaxError` (or `Exception`) to handle the case when an empty line is entered. However, using both `ValueError` and `SyntaxError`/`Exception`, the program handles entering an empty line in the same way (by following the `continue` statement). Why is that?

Comment: The program handles all exceptions the same way if catching `Exception` because `Exception` is superclass for both `ValueError` and `SyntaxError`, so no matter what type of exception you catch exactly, they all of `Exception` class. In real code you shouldn't use general `Exception` type, since you probably want to handle different errors in a different way, but it works fine if we wan't to catch all exception at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function like this:

```
def input_num(input_string):
    """ This function collects user input

    Args:
        input_string: message for user

    Return:
        user_input: returns user_input if it is a digit
    """

    user_input = raw_input("{}: ".format(input_string))
    if not user_input.isdigit():
        input_num(input_string)
    return int(user_input)
```

then call this function

```
user_num = input_num("Enter a number")
```

It will keep asking a user to provide a valid input until user puts one

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused why you ask for the input twice. You only need to ask them for input once. After that, you need to add a continue to your except statement. Otherwise, it will not repeat and just end the program. This is what your modified while loop should look like.

```
while not found:
    try:
        myNumber = int(input("Your guess: "), 10)
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter a number.")
        continue

    if myNumber == randomNumber:
        print("Correct!")
        found = True
    elif myNumber > randomNumber:
        print("Wrong, guess lower!")
    else:
        print("Wrong, guess higher!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `continue` keyword in your `except` to continue the loop.

`except ValueError:
     print('Enter a number')
     continue`